# MailCore2, always got nil on init MCOSMTPSession, MCOMessageBuilder and MCOAddress

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mailcore2

I'm a newbie to xcode and now using Xcode 6.3.2 to create an app with `MailCore2` to send email. Every time I create a variable for `MCOSMTPSession`, `MCOMessageBuilder` or `MCOAddress`, this variable always `'nil'`. To make it fast, I will copy my code here.

```
MCOSMTPSession *smtpSession = [[MCOSMTPSession alloc] init];
smtpSession.hostname = smtpServer;
smtpSession.port = (unsigned int)smtpPort;
smtpSession.username = fromAddress;
smtpSession.password = fromPass;
smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeTLS;

MCOMessageBuilder *builder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];
MCOAddress *from = [MCOAddress  addressWithMailbox:fromAddress];
NSMutableArray *toAddresses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
MCOAddress *to = [MCOAddress addressWithMailbox:toAddress];
[toAddresses addObject:to];
[[builder header] setFrom:from];
[[builder header] setTo:toAddresses];
[[builder header] setSubject:@"[Biz Cards App]"];
[builder setTextBody:[self.txtNotes text]];

NSData * rfc822Data = [builder data];
```

smtpSession, builder, from and to always got nil after I do init. Can anyone help me on this situation? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Above issue had been fixed by adding MailCore2 as a static library using this [Library](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/build-mac/README.md#build-for-iososx).

Now I got an error while accessing

```
NSData * rfc822Data = [builder data];
```

[image: MCOMessageBuilderError]

I got no further clue as the log showing nothing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you show how you got figured out that it was nil, did you try to NSLog() them?

Comment: Hi @DinhViêtHoà, I just solved this by adding MailCore2 as a static library. I used this [link] (https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/build-mac/README.md#build-for-iososx) _italic_ **bold** 'steps' to ad it as static library. I've added my question with my new error while accessing data method on MCOMessageBuilder. I will be more happier if you give some clue on how to solved my new question, thanks for one of MailCore creator to reply my question.

Comment: What's the value of fromAddress and toAddress?

Comment: fromAddress value is something@abc.com with NSString type and toAddress is test@test.com with NSString type also @DinhViêtHoà

Comment: You need to use MCOAddress types.